# Can I have Godzilla and the Titans as gods?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, religions-and-deities

I'm running a homebrew D&D 5e game in which I'd like to use [Godzilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla) and the other [Titans](https://wikizilla.org/wiki/Titan) from the Godzilla canonical universe as gods. I've looked online about how I can do this but I found nothing about them.

Can I make them into gods in my setting? How can I do that?

Comment: Hi Elijah. Welcome to the RPG stack exchange! Please consider taking the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Is it statblocks and/or mechanics, or similar, that you would need? Or something more lore-related?

Comment: @Jason_c_o both lol

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### You can.

You are free to set the deities of your world. See p. 10 of the DMG, under ["Gods of Your World"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/a-world-of-your-own#GodsofYourWorld):

> You can adopt one of these pantheons for your campaign, or pick and
> choose deities and ideas from them as you please.

You need to pick their alignment, symbol, and domains. As an example, they might be chaotic neutral, have a roaring dinosaur as their symbol, and have a domain of death or life.

For other titans/gods, make sure you cover most or all of the domains, so your players can pick who to worship and get appropriate benefits.

You also need to decide if they are a pantheon, or individual gods. Whatever you choose is reasonable. Pantheons are more closely knit, and individual gods are more free.

And there's lots of lore from the recent films to help adapt worship to them.

In the event that they fight them, here's a basic stat block made similar to Tiamat's stat block:

> #### Godzilla
>
> **Gargantuan monstrosity (titan)**
>
> ---
>
> **Armor Class** 25 (natural armor)
> **Hit Points** 615 (30d20 + 300)
> **Speed** 60 ft., swim 120 ft.
>
> ---
>
> 30 Str, 10 Dex, 30 Con, 10 Int, 26 Wis, 8 Cha
>
> ---
>
> **Saving Throws** Str +19, Dex +9, Wis +17
> **Skills** Nature +17, Perception +26, Religion +17
> **Damage Immunities** acid, cold, fire, lightning, poison; bludgeoning,
> piercing, and slashing damage from nonmagical attacks
> **Condition Immunities** blinded, charmed, deafened, frightened,
> poisoned, stunned
> **Senses** darkvision 240 ft., truesight 120 ft.
> **Languages** Common, Draconic, Japanese
> **Challenge** 30 (155,000 XP)
>
> ---
>
> ***Discorporation.*** When Godzilla drops to 0 hit points or dies, his
> body is disabled until a nuclear bomb or a large amount of nuclear
> energy is fed to it.
>
> ***Legendary Resistance (5/Day).*** If Godzilla fails a saving throw,
> he can choose to succeed instead.
>
> ***Limited Magic Immunity.*** Unless he wishes to be affected,
> Godzilla is immune to spells of 6th level or lower. He has advantage
> on saving throws against all other spells and magical effects.
>
> ***Magic Weapons.*** Godzilla's weapon attacks are magical.
>
> ***Resistance.*** Godzilla is immune to all non magical damage, and
> resistant to all magical weapons from those not from the gargantuan monstrosity (titan) type, deities included.
>
> ***Regeneration.*** Godzilla regains 30 hit points at the start of
> his turn.
>
> ---
>
> **Actions**
>
> ***Multiattack.*** Godzilla can use his Frightful Roar. He then makes
> three attacks: two with his claws and one with his tail.
>
> ***Claw.*** *Melee Weapon Attack:* +19 to hit, reach 15 ft., one target.
> *Hit:* 24 (4d6 + 10) slashing damage.
>
> ***Tail.*** *Melee Weapon Attack:* +19 to hit, reach 25 ft., one target.
> *Hit:* 28 (4d8 + 10) piercing damage.
>
> ***Frightful Roar.*** Each creature of Godzilla's choice that is
> within 240 feet of Godzilla and aware of his presence must succeed on
> a DC 26 Wisdom saving throw or become frightened for 1 minute. A
> creature can repeat the saving throw at the end of each of its turns,
> ending the effect on itself on a success. If a creature's saving throw
> is successful or the effect ends for it, the creature is immune to
> Godzilla's Frightful Presence for the next 24 hours.
>
> ---
>
> **Legendary Actions**
>
> Godzilla can take 3 legendary actions, choosing from the options
> below. Only one legendary action option can be used at a time, and
> only at the end of another creature's turn. The Godzilla regains spent
> legendary actions at the start of its turn.
>
> **Nuclear Fire (Costs 2 Actions).** Godzilla breathes nuclear fire in
> a 120-foot line that is 10 feet wide. Each creature in that line must
> make a DC 27 Dexterity saving throw, taking 88 (16d10) lightning
> damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.
>
> **Bite.** *Melee Weapon Attack:* +19 to hit, reach 20 ft., one target.
> *Hit:* 47 (7d10 + 10) bludgeoning damage.

Comment: I'd add that, if the OP is planning on these titans being the only gods, ideally the selection of gods should cover all of the available cleric domains.

Comment: @BBeast no the other gods still exist however the titans are older and slightly more powerful

Comment: @ElijahSanch In that case you don't need to worry about shoe-horning any of Godzilla and friends into the Knowledge or Trickery domains.

Comment: Just to add to your statblock, monstrosity (titan) is an existing creature type (Kraken, Tarrasque) and might be a good qualifier for the exception to their resistance (where you say "resistant to all magical weapons not from Titans.")

Comment: I added that to their stat block, along with a qualifier that they are resistant even to other gods who aren't Titans, so they can meet your requirement that titans are older and slightly more powerful.

Comment: Is there anything else you want from the answer, to get the tick?

Comment: could you make some of the other titans i could use mothra kong gihdora destroyah and rodan thanks